# tidyverse and a $ subsetting pecularity? intent for such behavior?

Tags: r, tidyverse, subset

`cdata` is a tibble (I used `haven` to import a `.sav` file into the `cdata` object).

Why does using `cdata$WEIGHT` instead of `WEIGHT` produce such a radical difference in the output below?

this code uses `cdata$WEIGHT` :

```
cdata %>% group_by(as.factor(state)) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), weighted_n = sum(cdata$WEIGHT))
```

produces an unwanted table:

[image]

this code uses `WEIGHT` :

```
cdata %>% group_by(as.factor(state)) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), weighted_n = sum(WEIGHT))
```

produces the correct table:

[image]

I realize that `tibble` has a different mental model than `base R`. However, the above difference doesn't make intuitive sense to me. What's the intent behind this difference in output when using a common column identification technique (`cdata$WEIGHT`)?

Comment: The first code returns the sum of the whole column `WEIGHT`, the second returns the sum per group.

Comment: @stefan - I appreciate the comment. However, to me, both `cdata$WEIGHT` and `WEIGHT` were simply ways of accessing a column name. Is that too simplistic a way to look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we having a grouping variable, `cdata$WEIGHT` extracts the whole column and thus the `sum` is from the whole column whereas if we use only `WEIGHT`, it returns only the data from the column for each group

---

If we really wanted to use `$`, then use the pronoun `.data`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise(Sepal.Length = sum(.data$Sepal.Length), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    Sepal.Length
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 setosa             250.
2 versicolor         297.
3 virginica          329.
```

which is identical to

```
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise(Sepal.Length = sum(Sepal.Length), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    Sepal.Length
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 setosa             250.
2 versicolor         297.
3 virginica          329.
```

Or use `cur_data()`

```
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
      summarise(Sepal.Length = sum(cur_data()$Sepal.Length), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    Sepal.Length
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 setosa             250.
2 versicolor         297.
3 virginica          329.
```

---

Whereas if we use `.$` or `iris$`, it extracts the whole column breaking the group attributes

```
iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise(Sepal.Length = sum(.$Sepal.Length), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    Sepal.Length
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 setosa             876.
2 versicolor         876.
3 virginica          876.
```